# Avoiding circular class dependencies when definitions are required

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <class T=A>
struct B {
   T a;
};

struct A {
    B<A> foo(){
       B<A> result;
       return result;
    }
};
```

How can I avoid having to use a template (mind the default parameter to see its usage).
The problem is that both classes require each other's definitions. But there's no "real" circular dependence as the template solution shows.

Comment: Compiles fine for me in DevStudio 2005. Don't forget that the template is instantiated when it is used not when it is declared.

Comment: Yeah, the above the work around that does work.
Removing the template is what does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exploit the fact that a forward declaration is sufficient in case you're returning by value (as is the case with `A::foo`):

```
struct B;

struct A {
  B foo();
};

struct B {
  A a;
};

B A::foo() {
  B result;
  return result;
}
```

Comment: While testing things out, I kept the foo implementation inline. Didn't think it would actually matter.